# Upgraded to laravel 6.0 - working migration now fails because of "default" method, might be a MariaDB problem

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, laravel-6, mariadb-10.1

I was wondering if I should open an issue on Laravel github, but I'm not sure it's a Laravel problem, maybe an Eloquent or MariaDB.

**The problem**
I upgraded recently to Laravel 6.0. When I try to reinstall my project (with empty database), and executing `php artisan migrate`, the first migration fails. The file contains only one table creation:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ltm_translations', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('status')->default(0);
        $table->string('locale');
        $table->string('group');
        $table->string('key');
        $table->text('value')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('ltm_translations');
}
```

And the error is because wrong SQL is generated. The `->default(0)` on the second column is translated to `status int not null default ('0')`.

That parenthesis stuff is causing my database to throw an exception. Here is the full SQL generated (extracted from error message).

```
create table `ltm_translations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `status` int not null default ('0'), `locale` varchar(255) not null,
  `group` varchar(255) not null, `key` varchar(255) not null, `value` text null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate 'utf8_bin' engine = innodb`
```

If I copy paste this query and replace `('0')` by `0` it works.
`(0)` and `('0')`fails.

The [official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#default-column-option) told me it was a valid syntax with expressions and such, but it mentions something about 10.2 version.

My MariaDB version replies:

```
mariadb --version
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.40-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

**The questions**
Is my MariaDB version the issue ?
Can I force Eloquent to generate syntax compatible to my MariaDB version or am I forced to upgrade mariaDB to 10.2+ ?

As this is not officialy supported by the production OS version (Ubuntu 18.04), that would be a terrible problem, any solution compatible with a production server is welcome.

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Please try : `$table->integer('status')->default('0');`

Comment: I can confirm that problem: migration: `$table->string('role')->default('editor');` causes `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('editor'), …` with laravel 6 but runs fine on laravel 5.8. I'm using docker mysql:5 `$mysql --version` yields `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`. Executing the sql manually with `default ('editor')` fails, with `default 'editor'` succeeds.

Comment: @dparoli same problem, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Works as of laravel 6.0.3

The issue has been fixed with laravel 6.0.3

### Working combinations prior to 6.0.3

- Laravel 5.8 mysql 5.7.27 *works*
- <s>Laravel 6.0.2 mysql 5.7.27</s> *doesn't work*
- Laravel 6.0.2 mysql 8.0.13 *works*

<s>Until this is fixed, it seems that you can either downgrade Laravel to 5.8 or upgrade mysql to 8.</s>

### Upgrading to mysql 8 on your development machine with docker

If you decide to upgrade to mysql 8.0.13, make sure to set `default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`. That's AFAIK a php problem, not a laravel problem.

For your reference:

```sh
$ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 7 thomas thomas 4096 Sep 11 10:28 data
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thomas thomas   61 Sep 11 10:11 php-compatible-password.cnf
-rwxrw-r-- 1 thomas thomas  316 Sep 11 10:14 start.sh
```

php-compatible-password.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

start.sh:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker run --rm -v "$PWD/php-compatible-password.cnf":/etc/mysql/conf.d/php-compatible-password.cnf -v "$PWD/data":/var/lib/mysql --user 1000:1000 --name mydb-mysql8 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -e MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead -e MYSQL_USER=homestead -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret -d mysql:8
```

laravel .env:

```
…
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.17.0.2
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
…
```

Where 172.17.0.2 is the result of

```sh
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mydb-mysql8
```

Comment: Laravel 6.0.3 has been released and fixes this problem of compatibility and now works with Mysql 5.7 and MariaDB 10.1. Can you edit so I can mark your answer as accepted ?

Comment: Done. Doesn't make much sense anymore as a solution for your question, but might be helpful for anyone with laravel < 6.0.3 or anyone who wants to upgrade to mysql 8 .

Comment: Yep, your answer contains valuable explanation. I could edit my post but it's more appealing to see a question "answered" when searching for a solution, and you deserve some credit because the [commit link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/b18be7620c214822103b38045bed264f0da2534d) you provided gave the solution to my problem :)